# Как хранить инфу о доступе к темам на форуме.

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Хочу потренироваться, пишу форум.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы автор темы мог указывать, кто из всех пользователей сможет видеть сообщения и кто может писать сообщения.
Неужели придётся создавать таблицу со столбцами типа таких: 
id_темы,
id_пользователя, 
привилегии (0 - не видит, 1 - только видит, 2 - видит и может писать)?
 И для каждого юзера и для каждой темы записывать сюда строку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте отдельную таблицу Группы. Каждому пользователю назначать к какой группе он относится. Для каждой темы указывать какая группа имеет какие привилегии.

Comment: Хочется иметь возможность именно индивидуальных привилегий.
Я думал о Вашем способе, но он будет работать не во всех ситуациях.
Например, я хочу создать несколько тем, под одной для каждой группы, и одну тему, в которую могут писать только главы каждой группы.

Comment: если для пользователей то лучше делать отдельной таблицей с полями temaID, userID, privilegii . И при заходе пользователя в тему првоерять не присутствует ли связка userID temaID в данной таблице

Comment: окей, то есть как я и думал. спасибо

Comment: @Dazar, в чем проблема добавить глав групп в отдельную группу и складывать привилегии?